# Python: Scan For File Data

Tags: python-3.x, antivirus, virus-scanning

I am planning on creating an antivirus program in Python. I am currently trying to scan for malicious file **data** rather than malicious file **names**, but am unsure how to implement it. I have virus sample files `VirusSample.exe` and `VirusSample.bat` to scan for. How do I implement this in Python? I would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: what would you scan for?

Comment: @MaartenFabré Thank you for your reply. I am trying to scan for contents of the virus file.

Answer (score 0):

I know how you can do it for batch files (*.bat).
You can scan for malicious codes, such as **rd c:\system32**, using
the split function (***batchString.split("\n")***).
If one of this type of codes is found in a batch file then it's malicious.

```
detection = False

malicious = ("rd c:\system32", "del c:\", "rd c:\")

filename = input("Batch File >> ")
fs = open(filename, 'r')
batch = fs.read()
fs.close()
codes = batch.split("\n")
for line in codes:
   for maliciouscode in malicious:
       if maliciouscode.lower() == line.lower():
           detection = True
if detection == True:
    print("Virus detected!")
```